# java: refactor encode cipher

Tags: java, refactoring

So I have implemented an encode method with a transposition cipher and I provide a key and a text message.

- visualization
  key: "dude"
  message: "hellobro"
  I assign numbers (int array) according to the alphabetical order of the key letters.

  D U D E
  0 1 3  2
  h  e l  l
  o b r o

sort arithmetically
D D E U
0 1 2  3
h l l e
o r o b

then "read" column-wise: encrypted-message: "holrloeb"

- implementation

```java
import java.util.*;

public class test1 {

    public static String encode(String textraw, String key){
        int csize = 0, index = 0;
        int[] numbers = {0,3,1,2};
        int mod = textraw.length() % key.length();
        int div = textraw.length() / key.length();
        // calculate size of column
        if (mod == 0) {
            csize = div;
        } else {
            csize = div + 1;
        }
        int[] snumbers = numbers.clone();
        Arrays.sort(snumbers);

        // Sort columns
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(textraw.length());

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < numbers.length; j++) {
                if (snumbers[i] == numbers[j]){
                    index = snumbers[j];
                    break;
                }
            }

            // create string column by column
            for (int j = 0; j < csize; j++) {
                if (index < textraw.length()) {
                    str.append(textraw.charAt(index));
                    index += numbers.length;
                }
            }
        }
        return str.toString();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String s = "hellobro";
        String keyk = "DUDE";
        System.out.println("encrypted -> "+encode(s,keyk));
    }

}
```

My question is how to refactor the encode method, at least getting rid of the second nested for loop?

I have tried omitting the index but haven't gotten it to work yet..
Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: "increase codestyle"? you would change the functionality to have nicer looking code? what exactly cypher is it you wrote?

Comment: thanks for the reply, I meant I would like to change the code structure of my columnar transposition cypher, but keep the functionality the same, as my code is already working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**General Remark**

Refactoring and code style are to some extent personal. So I guess not all people agree with me on this.
Some good practices are making sure your code is concise, but the class, method and variable names should also reflect what they are and/or do. The names you choose should help read the code. If a method gets too long, make a new one to improve readability.
In your current code, you could replace the calculation of *csize* with another method. You could also choose more readable variables, for example changing variable *str*.
There are complete books about proper Java code.  Martin Fowler wrote one of the more popular ones. So, these small remarks do not cover the refactoring topic at all.

**Goal of your Method**

You explained what you are trying to do. However, the use of your key (DUDE) seems to be unclear. It is actually not used. If you test your code with other keys, it has the exact same order. So, something seems off there.

**Code where one loop is omitted**

For all the people with a lot of experience looking at this: This can definitely be improved even more and/or can be structured differently. This code uses the same method parameters as the original and produces the same test results as the original post. I did not try to interpret the lack of use of the key (DUDE).

```
import java.util.Arrays;
class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cipher c = new Cipher();
        c.tests();
    }
}
class Cipher {
    public String encode(String textraw, String key) {
        StringBuilder resultString = new StringBuilder();
        Integer[] numbers = {0, 3, 1, 2};
        //split your textraw into substrings of 4
        String[] splitString = textraw.split("(?<=\\G.{"+numbers.length+"})");
        for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
            //get the index of the number I in your numbers array
            int foundIndex = Arrays.asList(numbers).indexOf(i);
            //should give 0,2,3,1 in the loop
            for(int k = 0; k < splitString.length; k++){
                //get the foundIndex from all substrings in splitStrings and add to the stringbuilder
                //you are looking for splitStrings[k].charAt(foundIndex)
                if(foundIndex < splitString[k].length()){
                    //This avoids errors when the last string is shorter than the maximum chars
                    resultString.append(splitString[k].charAt(foundIndex));
                }
            }
        }
        return resultString.toString();
    }


    public void tests() {
        String input;
        String key;
        input = "hellobro";
        key = "DUDE";
        System.out.println("Encoding " + input + " with key " + key + " gives result: " + encode(input, key));
        input = "dudedude";
        key = "DUDE";
        System.out.println("Encoding " + input + " with key " + key + " gives result: " + encode(input, key));
        input = "abcdabcdabc";
        key = "ABCD";
        System.out.println("Encoding " + input + " with key " + key + " gives result: " + encode(input, key));
    }
}
```

**Using the string key (DUDE)**

You could add a method that gets the sorted key from a string.
This method produces a sorted ArrayList.
So you would have to make numbers `ArrayList<Integer> numbers = getKeyArray(key);`
You would have to change `numbers.length` to `numbers.size()` and
foundIndex to `int foundIndex = numbers.indexOf(i);`

**Method getKeyArray with tests**

```
private ArrayList<Integer> getKeyArray(String key) {
        String alfabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        ArrayList<Integer> resultArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> charRank = new HashMap<>();
        for (int k = 0; k < key.length(); k++) {
             int alfabetIndex = alfabet.indexOf(Character.toLowerCase(key.charAt(k)));
             charRank.put(k, alfabetIndex);
        }
        charRank.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .sorted(Map.Entry.<Integer, Integer>comparingByValue()).forEach(e -> resultArrayList.add(e.getKey()));
        return resultArrayList;
    }

    public void testGetKeyArray() {
        String testInput;

        testInput = "ABDCEFG";
        System.out.println("Test getKeyArray with " + testInput);
        getKeyArray(testInput).forEach(System.out::println);

        testInput = "DUDE";
        System.out.println("Test getKeyArray with " + testInput);
        getKeyArray(testInput).forEach(System.out::println);
    }
```

**Output Examples getKeyArray**

```
"GFEABCD" Result: [3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 1, 0] 
"ABDCEFG" Result: [0, 1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6]
```